# Confusion over activechart and series collection

Tags: excel, vba

i wanted to plot a chart. I have researched from the internet and saw different methods to plot a graph
Some declare myChart as ChartObject, Shape, Chart. What is the difference between them?

Some uses codes such as

```
With myChart
        .Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("$E$3:$E$40")
End With
```

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Activate
With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart
```

```
With .SeriesCollection(1)
           .XValues = ARng
           .Values = BRng
End With
```

Whats the difference between these 3 methods? I wanted to clarify my doubts as i keep receiving errors while doing vba codes for creating a graph.

Comment: A ChartObject is a type of Shape which serves as a "container" for a Chart when the chart is sitting on a worksheet (and not on a Chart sheet).    A `ChartObject` has a `Chart` property which returns the actual chart itself.   Conversely `Chart.Parent` is the `ChartObject`   Worth noting it's not necessary to Activate a chart before working with it using VBA.

Comment: `srsNew.Name = "WhatEver"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `ChartObject` is a type of `Shape` which serves as a "container" for a `Chart` when the chart is sitting on a worksheet (and not on a Chart sheet). A ChartObject has a `Chart` property which returns the actual chart itself.

Conversely `Chart.Parent` is the `ChartObject`.

It's worth noting that it's not necessary to Activate a chart before working with it using VBA.

```vb
Set srsNew = .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        With srsNew
            .XValues = ColumnARngData
            .Values = ColumnBRngData
            Set xAxes = .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary)  ' [error 438]
```

Your With block scope is the `Series`, not the `Chart`.  A series has no `.Axes` property - you want the Chart for that.

If you want to loop over chart objects in different sheets then:

```vb
Dim s, Cht As Chart

For Each s in array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")
    Set Cht = Sheets(s).ChartObjects(1).Chart
    With Cht
         '...
         'configure Cht
         '...
    End with 
Next s
```

Comment: Understood! What about seriescollection and activechart "ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("sheet1").Activate
    With Application.ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary)" ? Whats the difference between them? Thank you for resolving my doubts!

Comment: The best approach is to use `ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("sheet1").Chart` and forget all about `ActiveChart`

Comment: i have 4 different sheet names, is it possible if i just write ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Chart instead? So that i can just call this subroutine

Comment: `ChartObjects` is a collection - it doesn't have a `Chart` property.

Comment: does that means i cant use ActiveSheet.Chart

Comment: If there's only a single ChartObject on each sheet you can use `Activesheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart` If there are multiple ChartObjects then you need to specify which one you want.

Comment: if there a way to loop it such that it can go to right sheet?